# Multiple txt files in raw folder | how to get txt on Item click in listview

Tags: java, android, textview, android-resources

I have multiple text files in *res/raw* folder. I want to get specific text files on item click from listview .

**b.java** (Activity which holds list array and rawid).

```
public class b extends Activity{
ListView lv;
int count=0;
int[] rawid={R.raw.addamtopm,R.raw.factorial,R.raw.fibonacci};

String[] content={
        "Add AM/PM to time using SimpleDateFormat",
        " Add or substract minutes to current time",
        "Add or substract days to current date",
        "Add or substract hours to current time"

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.b);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(content));
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.text_design,R.id.textView,arrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,        int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(b.this, b1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**b1.java**

```
public class b1 extends b {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.b1);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(readTextFile(b1.this,rawid[count]));
}

public static String readTextFile(Context ctx, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        while (( line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

When I click on list position `0` or position `1`, `R.raw.addamtopm` which is at position `rawid[0]` gets open ,I want to get txt files according to positon of on item click in listview.

**b.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    />
```

**b1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    />
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have been stucked here please help me guys.

Comment: Why do you have 3 raw files while your list have 4 items.

Comment: Rahul i actually have lost of raw files including with list items...for simplicity i just posted here little .

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass position value from first class(b.java) to second(b1.java).

`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(b.this, b1.class); intent.putextra("pos",position);
                startActivity(intent);
```

`

```
And just get value in b.java oncreate


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        int position;
      if (extras != null) {
        position= extras.getint("pos");
        // and get whatever type user account id is
       }
```

Then write if condition for every position

```
if(position==0){
     textView.setText(readTextFile(b1.this,R.raw.addamtopm);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks shekhar bro...your help is appreciated it worked.

Comment: I already tried but it ends with some popup of thanx for ur feedback